# Why use "Hell" to emphasize a statement?

Tags: emphasis

I was watching Rocky last night and one of the lines got me thinking.

I was wondering why we use *Hell* in sentences like "**A Hell of** a lot better than…," "**Hell**, that's the best thing that's ever happened to me" and "**Hell**, I don't know."

The first example was what got me thinking the most: "**A Hell of** a lot better than something." The contradiction between *Hell* and *better* was what seemed a bit confusing to me.

Comment: This question is best answered by another question: Why the hell not?

Comment: While "hell" certainly seems odd on its own, there are plenty of other words used with the same purpose. "We had a damn good time." "Why the fuck would you do that?" _Shit_ and _fuck_, in particular, seem to have an amazing number of viable uses that far surpasses the abilities of _hell_.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: Ya beat me to it.

Comment: @MrHen ... For many audiences, 'hell' is quite a bit more polite.  Pretty close to 'damn,' though.

Comment: @jgb: Yeah, I omitted obvious euphemisms for brevity.

Comment: What the heck...

Comment: In this usage "hell" is written lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hell* as an interjection is most likely short for *bloody hell*. The use of *bloody* to add emphasis to an expression is of uncertain origin. Recent research suggests that is is thought to have a connection with the 'bloods'—aristocratic rowdies who were the late 17th and early 18th century equivalents of 21st century 'Chavs' and 'Pikies.'

After the mid 18th century, *bloody* used as a swear word was regarded as unprintable, probably from the erroneous belief that it implied a blasphemous reference to the blood of Christ, or that the word was an alteration of 'by Our Lady.'

A widespread caution to using the term *bloody* arose, particularly in the US, and this is most likely where the use of simply *hell* came about.

Comment: I wouldn't mind some sources on this one. The US doesn't currently have a problem with _bloody_ and almost no one says _bloody hell_ unless they are mimicking a Brit.

Comment: [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bloody) provides a short history. [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/topicalwords/tw-blo1.htm) goes a bit further in depth. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody) suggests that "nowadays it is considered to be a very mild expletive, and unlikely to cause offence in most circles, with the exception of the most severe critics." I do agree that, to Americans, it is probably the most acute caricature of a British accent.

Comment: Brits pronounce it: "Bliddy Hill!"

Answer (score 1):

*A hell of* (or *one hell of*) is used as emphasis for something very bad or great. The expression is used both in American and British English.

> It cost us a hell of a lot of money.

Some expressions containing *hell* don't have a bad meaning. For example, *for the hell of it* means "just for fun," and *hell for leather* means "as fast as possible."

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, *Hell* was probably used to avoid using a less acceptable expletive which might have offended the film raters and reduced the number of children who watched the film.

Expletives are used in such circumstances purely for emphasis.  Originally there was a shock value, but that is now much weaker, largely due to overuse.

Comment: I wasnt meaning just in the movie though, more why is something "A hell of a lot better" in this case i've not heard any other expletive replacing hell, yet for the other examples you could freely replace hell with something else.